# Java Detecting Moving Objects in Another Application

Tags: java

I would like to have my Java applet monitor a fast moving rectangle in another non-Java program and press a certain key on the keyboard when it reaches a specific location. Can someone point me in the right direction as how to detect on-screen shapes?

Comment: Cheating on games?  Fortunately you'll need a trusted applet to do anything like that..

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be an Applet, I can make a Java Application to do the same. I just need to know how to process on screen images using Java.

Answer (score 1):

The API you're looking for is the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) API.

If the background is simple enough, detecting the rectangle should be trivial. If it isn't, you're looking at an object tracking problem. I understand [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) has plugins that can help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that ImageJ has many tools for processing still images. Would I have to capture the screen for that program every tick and use ImageJ to process the location or does it come with realtime processing features?

Comment: Yeah, you need to grab an image every frame, or perhaps every few frames. Java isn't exactly high speed when it comes to this kind of thing, and it may actually take more than the duration of a frame to process the image.

Comment: Which language would be more optimal to process frames?

Comment: C or C++ would probably give you the fastest solution.

Comment: Ah. Just started learning C++ so not really familiar with it yet and also I've written the bulk of the code base in Java already. I'll go with Java first and see how it goes. Thanks!